# Facebook share button is scraping a different page's info

Tags: facebook, button, share

I have this code for a Facebook custom share button:

```
<script>
function fbs_click() {
u=location.href;
t=document.title;
window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
return false;
}
</script>
<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" class="fb_share_link">
<img src="../../../../../image/photography/pics/fb-share.png" alt="Share this!" width="57" height="21" border="0">
</a>
```

This is supposed to scrape info from the page but for some reason it doesn't and it gets redirected to the site's main index.html.

I've tried adding facebook og tags and the extra code in the  but to no avail.

Any thoughts?

EDIT: Having been told that the share function has been deprecated, I tried to do this with the feed dialog:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?link=http://www.travel2italy.com/Travel/Italy/Company/photography/index.html&picture=http://www.travel2italy.com/image/photography/pics/homepage/florence1-home.jpg&name=travel2italy.com&caption=Photo%20Gallery&description=A%20Beautiful%20photo%20of%20Florence&redirect_uri=http://www.travelive.com" target="_blank">
<img src="../../../../../image/photography/pics/fb-share.png" alt="Tweet this!" width="57" height="21" border="0">
</a>
```

but when i click on the link it takes me to facebook and says an error occured, wth?!:(

EDIT 2:

I wasn't aware that the app_id argument is needed, signed up for an app and it works now, but it strips away the #section I have at the end of the link (i want it to link to a specific slide in a slideshow)

EDIT 3:

Now some of the share buttons using the sharer do seem to work but don't pull all the photos off the page for me to choose the one i want, this is insane-o, could it just be a caching issue?

Comment: You shouldn't be using sharer.php anymore, it's been deprecated for a very long time now. Suggest you use the like button, which also allows users to share a message together with the link :)

Comment: the issue here is that i need to have a custom button, can i do that with the like button?

Comment: The just use the Feed dialog, http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Comment: @CBroe tried it, see edit above

Comment: With all Facebook dialogs, you can add the parameter `show_error=1` to get more info about what went wrong. So: https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?show_error=1&link=http://www.travel2italy.com/Travel/Italy/Company/photography/index.html&picture=http://www.travel2italy.com/image/photography/pics/homepage/florence1-home.jpg&name=travel2italy.com&caption=Photo%20Gallery&description=A%20Beautiful%20photo%20of%20Florence&redirect_uri=http://www.travelive.com

Comment: @CBroe OK, i got it to work, i didn't know i had to make an app cause it needs the app_id argument. but the thing is, i'm trying to link inside a page to index.html#section and it won't let me and strips away the #section

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about right now.

Comment: @CBroe i am using the feed dialog but i want to link to www.domain.com/index.html#section and it won't let me, it seems to strip away the #section and when i click on the link it takes me to www.domain.com, which i don't want because the #section is actually a slide in a slideshow

Comment: You are giving a URL as a GET parameter here – so of course you have to __URL-encode__ it properly before doing so.

Comment: @CBroe you mean within the feed dialog link? how would i do that to make sure it accepts the full path with the #section at the end?